# Check if a `read` would return EOF without consuming any data

Tags: c, linux, pipe, posix

I have a C program that receives data from another program over a (Linux) pipe. I want the program to behave differently if the pipe was closed before writing any data.

The natural way to do this is to try to read from the pipe and check if I get `EOF`, but that consumes some data from the pipe if there is any available, and (as far as I know) there's no way to put data "back" in a pipe.

The part of the program where I want to check if the pipe is empty is pretty far away from where I process the data, so I'd rather not have to deal with saving the data from my first read until then.

Is there any way to check if a pipe is empty (`read` would return `EOF`) without consuming any data in the case it's not empty?

Note: I *do* want this to block if the pipe has not been written to or closed yet.

Comment: `poll()` `select()` ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, `poll()` and `select()` do not serve here.  They can tell you whether a read attempt would block, but I don't think they distinguish between the case where `read()` would transfer some bytes without blocking and the case where `read()` would signal EOF without blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do what you describe.  The way to determine whether you have reached the end of a non-seekable file such as a pipe is to attempt to read from it.  This is not just the natural way, it is *the* way.

> but that consumes some data from the pipe if there is
> any available,

Yes.

> and (as far as I know) there's no way to put data
> "back" in a pipe.

That depends.  If you are reading with POSIX `read()`, then no.  If you are wrapping the the pipe end in a `FILE` and using stdio functions to read it then there is [`ungetc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ungetc).

Nevertheless, this:

> The part of the program where I want to check if the
> pipe is empty is pretty far away from where I process the data

seems like a design problem.  You cannot know whether you will ever get data until you actually *do* get data or see EOF.  The process(es) at the write end of the pipe can delay an arbitrary amount of time before doing anything with the pipe, and even if that process is provided by you, you cannot be fully in control of this aspect of its behavior.  Thus, it doesn't make much sense to try to check for EOF before you're ready, in some sense, to consume data, because you cannot rely on getting an answer without blocking.

> , so I'd
> rather not have to deal with saving the data from my first read until
> then.

I suppose you must want to avoid performing some kind of heavyweight initialization in the event that there is no data to process.  Ok, but I don't see what the big deal is.  You need to provide storage into which to read the data anyway.  What's wrong with something like this:

```
void consume_pipe_data(int fd) {
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    ssize_t count;

    count = read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (count == 0) {
        handle_no_data();
        return;
    } else if (count > 0) {
        perform_expensive_initialization();
    }
    do {
        if (count == -1) {
            handle_error();
            return;
        }
        consume_data(buffer);
        count = read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    } while (count);
}
```

The point is not that that's necessarily an appropriate structure for your program, but rather that it is possible to structure the program so that storing the data, if any, from the initial read is pretty clean and natural.

Comment: Regarding the "design problem" -- My program creates an "archive file" of sorts from several input files, some of which are actually pipes from programs that calculate the data to go in them.  When writing the header I need to know if the files are zero-length (because those are omitted) but I'd rather not read in the data until writing the data section for that file.  It's kind of awkward to have to buffer the first small amount of each file somewhere, and some of the files are big so I can't just buffer the whole thing in memory.  I'd welcome ideas to fix that but don't have any good ones.

Comment: @GavinS.Yancey, you have numerous options, but the bottom line is that you need more structure.  Since you are in control (I presume) of both ends of the pipes, you could layer a mini protocol over the raw data that communicates metadata such as, at least, whether there are any data.  That way there is always something to read.  Alternatively, instead of using file descriptors directly, you could wrap them in `FILE` objects via `fdopen()`, making `ungetc()` available to you.

Answer (score 4):

If you used Unix domain stream sockets instead of pipes – meaning you replace your `pipe(fds)` calls with [`socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, fds)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) –, you could use [`recv(fd, dummybuffer, 1, MSG_PEEK)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) to read/receive one byte of data, without removing it from the receive buffer.

You can combine `MSG_PEEK` with `MSG_DONTWAIT` if you don't want to block, or with `MSG_WAITALL` if you want to block until the entire buffer can be filled.

The differences between an Unix domain stream socket and a pipe are minimal.  The stream socket is bidirectional, but you can use [`shutdown(fd, SHUT_WR)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) (or `SHUT_RD`) to close the "write end" (resp. "read end"), meaning if the other end tries to read from the socket, they'll get an immediate end-of-stream (`read()`, `recv()` etc. return 0).  (Closing the "read end" means that when the other end tries to write to the socket, they'll get `EPIPE`.)

Right now, I cannot even think of a reason why a program that works with a pipe would not work with an Unix domain stream socket pair.

If you use named pipes, you do need to change `mkfifo()` and `open()` to `socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)` followed by a `bind()` to the socket address.  `read()`, `write()`, and even the higher-level standard I/O facilities work just fine on top of an Unix domain stream socket (use `fdopen()` to convert the socket descriptor to a `FILE` handle).

If you cannot modify the readers, you can create a minimal dynamic library that interposes `openat()` (that's what current C library uses underneath `fopen()`), calling original `openat()` for all except the socket path, say named in an environment variable, and instead creates a socket and binds to the socket path for that one.  When executing the reader binaries, you just set `LD_PRELOAD` to point to this interposing library.

In other words, I do believe there are no real obstacles for switching from pipes to Unix domain stream sockets.

You cannot use `recv()` with pipes, because pipes are implemented in Linux using a special filesystem, not sockets.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a dummy-write.  If your stdin has reached eof, it is a non-blocking mechanism to determine if you've reached EOF, without any more sophisticated tools.

```
    if( write( fileno(stdin), 0, 0 ) != 0 )
        return 1; // Is end-of-file.
```